# error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get product data from firebase database and displaying its properties in browser. I have defined `product` object as empty initially and when I get data from firebase and then show it by using two way binding like `[(ngModel)]="product.title"`. but get the above mentioned error. please help.

### product.service.ts

```
    getProduct(productId){
        return this.db.object('/products/' + productId ).valueChanges();
      }
    }
```

### product-form.component.ts

```
    export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit{
    
      categories$;
      product={};
    
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route :ActivatedRoute,
        private categoryService: CategoryService,
        private productService:ProductService) {
    
        this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
    
        let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
        if (id) this.productService.getProduct(id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
        
      }
```

### product-form-component.html

```html
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
                    <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" 
                    type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of the Product" 
                    id="title"  required> <!--  Error [(ngModel)]="product.title" , Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'-->
                    
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
                        Title is required        
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unlike a lot of the forums out there, we expect a bit more out of questioners. Take the [tour] and read [ask] to discover what those expectations are. First and foremost among those expectations; research. [A search for TS2339 on SO found about 1933 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ts2339+is%3Aq). Please look through those first and see if any answer your question.

Comment: yes i had checked similar question answers but it didn't solve my problem. so, thus i asked this question

Comment: Try this `[(ngModel)]="product?.title"`

Comment: Not working, Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your type as `any`. A better way would be to define the type or simply let typescript infer the type, something like

```
    export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit{
    
      categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
      product = {
        title: ''
      }
    
      constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route :ActivatedRoute,
        private categoryService: CategoryService,
        private productService:ProductService) {
    
        let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
        if (id) {
          this.productService.getProduct(id).pipe(
             take(1)
           ).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
        }
        
      }
```

Comment: i have more properties like tittle inside my product object which i am getting from firebase and made some changes to my product object but getting that same error

Comment: Have you changed this line `subscribe(p => this.product = p);`

Comment: Can you copy paste the whole error and share

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for the product object and add type to the `product` variable

```js
interface Product {
  title: string
  // otherProps: string
}

export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  // added a definite assertion telling TS that it will be assigned before access
  private product!: Product
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route :ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService:ProductService
  ) {
      let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
      if (id) {
        this.productService.getProduct(id).pipe(
          take(1)
        ).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: error : Property 'product' does not exist on type 'ProductFormComponent.

Comment: @codeBreaker on which line you getting the error